# Modify contents of basic_ostream object in c++ or, deleting data contents of basic_ostream object

Tags: c++, stream, ostream

I get a `ostream` object reference in a function. It contains a string which I need to modify. 
I copied the contents of the `ostream` using `rdbuf()` function into a `stringstream`. 
Now I need to copy the updated stringstream (the underlying string that is) back to the ostream object. How can I do this?

I searched ways of erasing the contents of the ostream, but could not find one.

Note: I cannot change the implementation of other functions, i.e., I an unable to use `ostringstream` (which I know can solve my problem).

Comment: Are you sure you have an actual `std::ostream` object instance and not a reference? And I would argue that if you need to modify some output *after the fact* is something that smells of bad design. Besides, how do you know that the actual string you want to modify is still *in* the buffer? What if it has already been flushed?

Comment: I am sorry it is a reference, not a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change the current position in the stream using `ostream::seekp()` or `streambuf::pubseekpos()`:

```
std::ofstream out;

out.seekp(-10, std::ios_base::cur); // move back 10 positions from current location
out.rdbuf()->pubseekpos(12); // move to position 12
```

Keep in mind that:

- this might fail if the underlying destination of the data does not support seeking (e.g. the streambuf might actually write the data to a socket let's say)
- if it works for your particular type of stream, you have to keep count of positions and lengths and how much you overwrite (if the new value has a different length then the old value that you want to replace in the stream).