# Copying streams in C++

Tags: c++, stream

The following program prints 0.

```
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string subjectString("subject");
  std::ostream tempStream(NULL);
  tempStream << subjectString;
  std::ostream& updatedStream = tempStream;
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << updatedStream;
  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Why?

EDIT

As per Niall's sugesstion, I tried:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string subjectString("subject");
  std::stringbuf buffer;
  std::ostream tempStream(&buffer);

  buffer.sputn(subjectString.c_str(), subjectString.size());

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << tempStream;
  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Even this prints an address. Not the actual string.

Comment: Why do you construct `tempStream` with `NULL`? What is the use of the `updatedStream` reference?

Comment: I construct `tempStream` with `NULL` because I am not allowed to simply do `std::ostream tempStream` (I guess the ctor is private or something). updatedStream reference has no use in this snipper per se, but in a separated codebase I am required to modify the contents of a ostream. So, I copy the contents of the ostream into a stringstream using rdbuf(), then create another ostream object to copy the updated contents into (because I don't know how to erase contents of a ostream object). However, in that function I have to return an ostream reference, so I am trying that here.

Comment: What compiler do you use? For me [it doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5229470a6754aca) using GCC 5.1 or Clang 3.6

Comment: @AntonSavin GCC 4.1 (don't ask why :'( )

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) instead of an anonymous `std::ostream` without any buffer? Actually, only use `std::ostream` when you make generic output functions, and then only references to `std::ostream`, you should almost never construct `std::ostream` objects yourself.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Of course I must use `std::ostringstream`, but the problem I am trying  to solve is part of a bigger codebase where there is a lot of function hierarchy implemented in `ostream`. I cannot change all that.

Comment: I think it's time you try to describe the *actual* problem you try to solve, not aksing us to help you with your current solution (related reading: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), and I still maintain that you should not use actual `std::ostream` objects instances directly.

Comment: This is my actual problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132025/modify-contents-of-basic-ostream-object-in-c-or-deleting-data-contents-of-bas

Comment: I would not directly manipulate the buffer, you should rather use the stream instead `tempStream.write`. You have already mentioned that this is part of a larger problem. `ss << tempStream;` doesn't compile, so it is difficult to continue with the demo code past the initialisation of the first stream with the buffer and streaming content into that stream. If all you want to do with the code is check if the data is in the buffer, then you could use `tempStream.rdbuf()->sgetn(...)`

Comment: @Niall the larger problem is basically changing the contents of a ostream reference from A to B. It can be easily done if I can simply erase the entire contents of the ostream reference, but I am don't know how to do even that much.

Comment: @Wildling. This could be a case in which direct manipulation of the buffer is needed (in much the same way as the stream would). Your implementation would need to be well tested since the is not "the usual" way of doing things, but it can work; `.rdbuf()` is the manner in which you can get to the underlying buffer.

Comment: @Niall yes, I used rdbuf() previously to fetch the underlying data. Can you please tell me how to set the data ? there is no set_buf() that I could find ..

Comment: @Niall Do you know how I can erase all contents of a ostream ?

Comment: I don't have an exact snippet (maybe that's another question), but you can do this by resetting the position(s) of the put and get areas to be the same (see the positioning, put and get area functions of the buffer). I think you standard library implementation of stringstream could also offer some useful hints.

Comment: @niall yes, I was able to do it using std::ostream::seekp

Comment: @Wildling. Excellent. Consider posting an answer to the first question on this as well. I think that it would be great to have something with detail on how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction of `std::ostream` requires a buffer (not NULL).

In addition, `basic_stream` objects are not copyable;

> `basic_ostream( const basic_ostream& rhs ) = delete;`

Reference;

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream

Try something more like this;

```
// ...
std::stringbuf buffer;
std::ostream tempStream(&buffer);
// ...
```

To associate a buffer with the stream.

*Following on some of the discussions and edits;*

In general, I would not directly manipulate the buffer, you should rather use the stream instead `tempStream.write(...)`. The exact details are beyond the immediate question/problem; being the initialisation of the first stream with the buffer and streaming content into that stream. If all you want to do with the code is check if the data is in the buffer, then you could use `tempStream.rdbuf()->sgetn(...)`.

You have already mentioned that this is part of a larger problem.

In the context of some the comments here and the [original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31132025/3747990); this could be a case in which direct manipulation of the buffer is needed (in much the same way as the stream would). Your implementation would need to be well tested since this is not "the usual" way of working with streams, but it can work; `.rdbuf()` is the manner in which you can get to the underlying buffer. I don't have an exact snippet (maybe that's another question), but you can "clear the buffer" by resetting the position(s) of the put and get areas to be the same (see the positioning, put and get area functions of the buffer - [`std::ostream::seekp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) was mentioned as being used to deal with this). I think you standard library implementation of `stringstream` could also offer some useful hints.

Comment: So, it is impossible for me to create a ostream reference and initialize it to another ostream object?

Comment: @Wildling. The reference is fine, it doesn't make a copy at. Creating a reference to an object is not the same as coping it (no copy is made).

Comment: OK, can you tell me the correct way of initializing (since NULL is clearly wrong) tempStream such that I can do `tempStream << subjectString;` and get the contents of subJectStream into tempstream?

Comment: @Wildling. I've updated it with a sample of the initialisation.

Comment: I tried that, could not get it to work. I have updated the question with the details, can you kindly take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Because `tempStream` has no stream to hold anything.

`ss.str()` returns NULL (0).

Comment: So `tempStream << subjectString;` has no effect? It does not copy subjectStream to tempStream?

Comment: It's not able to copy anything cause there no buffer to hold anything